# Set opacity of Yandex Placemark

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps

I need to set opacity of my Placemark in Yandex Map. But I could not find a way to give it as a prop or any other way. There is nothing about it on documentation. I do not want to add just new transparent marker to my assets folder.

Here is how I create my placemark

```
 const courierReachMarker = new ymaps.Placemark([$scope.map.courierReachMarker.coords.latitude, $scope.map.courierReachMarker.coords.longitude], null, {
          iconLayout: 'default#image',
          iconImageHref: `/${$scope.map.courierReachMarker.options.icon.url}`,
          iconImageSize: [30, 30],
          iconImageOffset: [-15, -30],
          draggable: false,
          courierMarker: true,
        });
        $scope.yMap.courierReachMarker = courierReachMarker;
        $scope.yMap.geoObjects
          .add($scope.yMap.courierReachMarker);
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template:

```
var squareLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="placemark_layout_container"><img src="https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/icon_customImage/images/myIcon.gif" width=50 height=50/></div>');
```

Add css rule:

```
.placemark_layout_container img{ 
    opacity: 0.3
    }
```

And use it:

```
var squarePlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
    [55.725118, 37.682145], {}, {
        iconLayout: squareLayout,
        iconShape: {
            type: 'Rectangle',
            coordinates: [
                [-25, -25], [25, 25]
            ]
        }
    }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjq68obx/1/